# Angular/Google App Engine/Go: Use google authentication to access my protected module (login: admin) with angular

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, authentication, go

In App Engine Go, I have a frontend module protected with the .yaml config login: admin.

```
handlers:
  - url: /(.+)
    static_files: static/\1
    upload: static/(.*)
    secure: always
    login: admin

  - url: /
    static_files: static/index.html
    upload: static/index.html
    secure: always
    login: admin
```

This module gives me a static content (html) with an Angular App. So, to access this module https://frontend-dot-project.appspot.com I must be logged with a project Admin user. If I'm not logged it redirects me to a Google Login page, then redirects back and the access is granted. It's all handled by App Engine login option. Then on, any resource needed by the browser (js, imgs) is granted.

But, I have another module Backend that is a restful one, also protected with login: admin.

```
handlers:
 - url: /.*
   script: _go_app
   secure: always
   login: admin
```

The Angular app will, in time, call the https://backend-dot-project.appspot.com, and it also needs the same admin authentication. If I just call it from Angular, it throws not authorized error.

```
function myController($http){
  $http.get(
    'https://backend-dot-project.appspot.com/endpoint', 
    {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ TOKEN??? }}
  ).then(success, error)
}
```

If I just access the Backend endpoint on a browser, it will also authenticates with the google Admin user logged, or handle the login page.

But, how can I authenticate the Angular call using the Admin user logged? It's the same that have just accessed the Angular app.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? If so, could you please update your question? Thx @esze

Comment: @Esze - Did you find a solution to this? I'm looking for a similar setup as I'd like to avoid building everything in python - would prefer and love to have the frontend and backend separation! Thanks!